# Stata: Create a dummy out of multiple string entries in one cell

Tags: string, stata

I have a dataset which looks like this (of course much bigger, with up to 5 entries in one cell):

```
iso3   variable
GBR    1994
USA    
FRA    1993, 1995
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
iso3    year    dummy
GBR     1993    0
GBR     1994    1
GBR     1995    0
USA     1993    0
USA     1994    0
USA     1995    0
FRA     1993    1
FRA     1994    0
FRA     1995    1
```

where the problem, of course, is `FRA`. I was thinking of writing a string search and looping through all years to create a dummy if it finds the year but I don't know how to apply that to each `iso3` category.

Is there something similar to the `apply` functions in R in Stata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of `split`, `reshape`, and `fillin`

```
clear
input str3 iso3 str20 var
GBR    "1994"
USA    
FRA    "1993, 1995"
end
split var, parse(",") destring generate("yr")
list 
drop var
reshape long yr, i(iso3) j(junk)
generate dummy = 1
fillin iso3 yr
replace dummy = 0 if dummy==.
drop if yr==.
drop junk _fillin
list, sepby(iso3)
```

gives us

```
     +---------------------+
     | iso3     yr   dummy |
     |---------------------|
  1. |  FRA   1993       1 |
  2. |  FRA   1994       0 |
  3. |  FRA   1995       1 |
     |---------------------|
  4. |  GBR   1993       0 |
  5. |  GBR   1994       1 |
  6. |  GBR   1995       0 |
     |---------------------|
  7. |  USA   1993       0 |
  8. |  USA   1994       0 |
  9. |  USA   1995       0 |
     +---------------------+
```